# Ask about KV in logstash

Tags: logstash

I have a sample log.
  "a=1&b=1&c=1"

I separated the parameters using KV.

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{DATA:rawparam}}
  }

  KV {
    source => "rawparam"
    target => "param"
    field_split = > "&?#"
    allow_duplicate_values => false
  }
}
```

The results are as follows. However, I want to set certain fields of param to the root location.

```
{
  "type" : "log",
  "rawparam" : "a=1&b=1&c=1",
  "param" : {
    "a" = "1",
    "b" = "2",
    "c" = "3"
  }
}
```

The results below are the results I want. Is this possible in Logstash?

```
{
  "type" : "log",
  "rawparam" : "a=1&b=1&c=1",
  "param" : {
    "a" = "1",
    "b" = "2"    
  },
  "c" = "3"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By specifying 'target', you're telling logstash where to put all the kv fields, so they end up under 'params'.

You can either remove the 'target' option (and logstash will put all the fields at the root level), use mutate->rename (to move [params][b] to [b]), or use ruby (to loop across a larger set of fields to rename).